# Showing that $Y$ must be a constant

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that the random variable $Y = Z - X$ is independent of $Z$ and $X$, where $X$ and $Z$ are random variables. Show that $Y$ must be a constant.

**My attempt:** I know that independence implies uncorrelatedness. Since $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, we have $\textrm{Cov}(Z-X, Z) = 0$, and since $Y$ and $X$ are independent, we have $\textrm{Cov}(Z-X, X)=0$.

To show that $Y$ is constant, I know that I have to show that $\textrm{Var}(Y)=\textrm{Var}(Z-X)=0$ because anything that has a zero variance must be a constant. So I have $$\textrm{Var}(Z-X) = \textrm{Var}(Z) + \textrm{Var}(X) - 2 \textrm{Cov}(Z,X)$$

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Cov(Z-X,Z) = Cov(Z,Z) - Cov(X,Z) = Var(Z)-Cov(X,Z) = 0$$

$$Cov(Z-X,X) = Cov(Z,X) - Cov(X,X) = Cov(X,Z) - Var(X) = 0$$

Comment: @expiTTpzo How did you get from $Cov(Z-X,Z)$ to $Cov(Z,Z) - Cov(X,Z)$?

Comment: Covariance is billinear. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Relationship_to_inner_products

Comment: $Cov(Z-X,Z) = E((Z-X)Z) - E(Z-X)E(Z) = E(Z^2)-E(XZ)-E(Z)^2+E(X)E(Z) = (E(Z^2)-E(Z)^2) - (E(XZ)-E(X)E(Z)) = Var(Z) - Cov(X,Z)$

Comment: Got it! This one is easier for me to understand.